# Can a planet have both magma volcanoes and cryovolcanos?

Tags: geophysics, volcanology

I know that the Jovian ice moons have been speculated to have cryovolcanos. I was thinking of the ice planet of Hoth from Star Wars and in one of the video games; it has regular volcanic activity. However, it’s still an ice world so can an ice planet have cryovolcanos along with regular volcanos?

Comment: Interesting question! I don't think we currently have any example of this in the solar system. But I don't see any major obstacle, although you'd need a conjunction of several parameters for this to occur. But after all, Earth has silicate volcanoes, carbonate volcanoes, mud volcanoes... So having both silicate and ice volcanoes does not seem impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it's entirely possible. According to theory ice volcanoes are caused by the buildup of pressure from some sort of heat source. Most that we know of are caused by tidal forces, intense gravity from Jupiter or Saturn squishing a moon. A rupture forms on the surface of the ice and pressure is released in the form of a plume. Enceladus (a moon of Saturn) has cryovolcanism, the theory is that the heat comes from its core rather then tidal forces, not volcanism exactly. There's no reason that the heat couldn't come from volcanism, we just have no examples in our solar system.

If you took Earth and pushed its orbit out past the ice line you'd get a world like you describe. There would be surface volcanoes and under-water volcanoes that would cause ice geysers through the oceans' thick crusts of ice.